# .htaccess reditrect subdirectory page to root

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I got a website running and in the subdirectory domain.com/blog/ I installed a Wordpress blog website. The subdirectory contains dozen of blog articles, for example
domain .com/blog/testing
domain .com/blog/example
domain .com/blog/article1
domain .com/blog/article2

*And what I am trying to do is to rewrite and redirect (a single page) domain.com/blog/example to domain.com/example*

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems javascript redirect is better than htaccess redirect for your case.
Simply edit your article using a code editor in wordpress.

```
<script>window.location = "http://www.yourhomepage.com";</script>
```